# how to select multiple sets of elements in Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I'm selecting a single element called "detalleItemDescription" in Sencha Touch 2 like this:

```
this.getDetalleItem().down('#detalleItemDescription').setData(record.data);
```

how to select multiple?

```
this.getDetalleItem().down('#detalleItemDescription','#second','#third').setData(record.data);
```

Is that possible? how to do that?

Thanks!!

Comment: What are your `#detalleItemDescription`, `#second` and `#third` components? `textfields`?

Comment: @roadRunner: all of them are Ext.Container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Ext.ComponentQuery.query` that accepts a comma separated list and will return an Composite collection you can enumerate upon.

Or you can use the query method directly on your object.

```
this.getDetalleItem().query('#detalleItemDescription','#second','#third').each(function(item) { item.setData(record.data) }) ;
```